# Run multiple instances of Telegram

Tags: macos

I have 2 iphones and use 2 seperate Telegrams.  The 2nd one is assigned to me by the external project phone I'm assigned to and that company uses Telegram extensively.  There is 1000's of employees communicating in multiple groups.  There's a lot of traffic.

Current setup:

- Main account / OSX: Official OSX telegram.app
- Main account / iOS: Official iOS telegram.app
- 2nd account / OSX: Official Windows app running in an VMWare XP box
- 2nd account / iOS: iOS Anyways Messenger

For the iPhone I could live with the Anyways Messenger even though it hasn't been updated for a long time and contains a lot of bugs.

For OSX I'd really would like to be able to run 2 instances of the official Telegram app, without having to run my VMWare.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Some OSX Apps, such as "Preview", you can just duplicate in your App folder, and that'll let you run two copies simultaneously. They *will* share the same prefs file, and possibly other files as well, so some caution is needed. I don't have a copy of Telegram to test, and see how that behaves.

Comment: I have tried all of the normal stuff before asking this question.  So while your suggestion is a very logic one it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Telegram offers 2 official versions of their OSX app.

Version 1 is the official maintained version, both available as direct .dmg download on the Telegram website and in the Appstore.

Version 2 is also official, but it's the deprecated objective-c version, also offered as direct .dmg download.  While it's no longer supported, it does still run - and uses separate user credentials.  Newer features are not available, but otherwise it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

They're all official:

### Desktop

1. [Cross-platform Telegram for desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telegram-desktop/id946399090)
2. [macOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telegram/id747648890)
3. [Deprecated objective-c version](https://telegram.org/dl/macos/objc)

### Mobile

1. [Regular Telegram Messenger](https://itunes.apple.com/app/telegram-messenger/id686449807)
2. [Telegram X](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telegram-x/id898228810) - another [official variation](https://telegram.org/blog/telegram-x) of Telegram

### More Apps

For the full list of Telegram apps available, [go to their official list](https://telegram.org/apps).

### General note

If you're using the cross-platform version, you can use a portable version and "install" it as many times as you want, in different folders, to have unlimited number of Telegram accounts accessible from your desktop.

The multiple users feature already arrived to Android, and I believe it will also arrive to iOS eventually.